# How to get the addr from this transaction

Tags: transactions, address

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/2ccc3f59d28c709770a8bc478b112e10feda4bf55197c2e48deaa0eb6bca0311?show_adv=true

The SCRIPT in the transaction is:

DUP HASH160 PUSHDATA(20)[482f0027662731277fdfa3b7f639c976a3bab11e] EQUALVERIFY CHECKSIG

What is 482f0027662731277fdfa3b7f639c976a3bab11e ?

It is not a pubKey.
RIPEMD160(SHA256(482f0027662731277fdfa3b7f639c976a3bab11e)=146sN8tLxV2xueQXQgMJkMZi2hFazEuV8F.

The result is not the address(17afxUJouat3fkaaQ9tZrDThxdkXGL4WrM) in the blockchain.info either.

How we convert the 482f0027662731277fdfa3b7f639c976a3bab11e to it's addr？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`482f0027662731277fdfa3b7f639c976a3bab11e` is `HASH160` (`RIPEMD160(SHA256())`) of the public key. The hash is the most important part of addresses (addres: network byte + hash + checksum).

You can look at how P2PKH script works step-by-step [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Standard_Transaction_to_Bitcoin_address_.28pay-to-pubkey-hash.29).

Comment: what you mean "It"? The address 17afxUJouat3fkaaQ9tZrDThxdkXGL4WrM?

Comment: @Capemer I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I gusses the command `decoderawtransacton` can help you

Comment: Hi @老板鱼丸粗面, can you provide some more context, maybe some documentation, an example output and how to run the command? Short answers often don't provide enough context to be helpful.

Comment: The question here is how to convert 482f0027662731277fdfa3b7f639c976a3bab11e to it's address 146sN8tLxV2xueQXQgMJkMZi2hFazEuV8F

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer here, the final code for the question is:

```
import hashlib
import base58 

def gen_addr(hash_code):
  key_hash = '00' + hash_code
  # Obtain signature:
  sha = hashlib.sha256()
  sha.update( bytearray.fromhex(key_hash) )
  checksum = sha.digest()
  sha = hashlib.sha256()
  sha.update(checksum)
  checksum = sha.hexdigest()[0:8]
  address = (base58.b58encode( bytes(bytearray.fromhex(key_hash + checksum)))).decode('utf-8')
  return address, key_hash, checksum
```

gen_addr('482f0027662731277fdfa3b7f639c976a3bab11e')='17afxUJouat3fkaaQ9tZrDThxdkXGL4WrM'